# Is there a way to test an Asterisk from the terminal, without a phone

Tags: asterisk

I have installed asterisk I want to test I'm able to log in. I have in Go GoGrid. when I setup the IP, the extension and password I get it cannot reach the server. I'm able to ssh into the machine.

Is there a way to test from the console that asterisk is running and receiving connections ?
I would like to test from the terminal that I can connect with that extension and password ?
There might a problem with Asterisk running on GoGrid ?

Thanks, 
Federico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Federico.  Firstly, I run four Asterisk PBXs on GoGrid, so I know it works just fine.
Make sure your IP Tables is allowing SIP, IAX2 & RTP connections;  by default, the images supplied don't.
To see if Asterisk is "seeing" a connection, use "asterisk -rvvv" to connect to the running Asterisk console.  Use "sip show peers" or "iax2 show peers" to see if your phones and trunks are connected properly.
I also find that the "iftop" utility is -very- useful for making sure that remote devices are even trying to reach your PBX eth0.

Answer (score 3):

from ssh you can go asterisk console by

```
asterisk -r
```

to check inbound sip packets come via firewall use

```
asterisk -r
sip set debug on
```

more info can be found at [asterisk debug page  on voip info](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+debugging)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can check whether Asterisk is alive by a console SIP client such as Linphonec and pjsua.

http://www.linphone.org/eng/documentation/guide/linphonecsh-control.html
http://www.pjsip.org/pjsua.htm